# CSS em vs px (rounding errors)

Tags: css, units-of-measurement

I've been working on a personal website (so, time is not an issue here) and I made a base stylesheet where I take care of all the font-sizes, border-widths, line-heights and the like.
I made an effort to use ems all the way, but when I tested the website on other browsers (eg. Chromium) the content didn't match my "pixel-perfect" grid.

So, my question here is, should I use px instead? I mean, I know ems are "the way to go" but nowadays most browsers implement fullpage zoom (they don't resize just the text) and when it comes to dealing with border-width and line-heights, px are more comfortable, because I can avoid subpixel rounding altogether.

What's your take on this? (btw, supporting IE is not one of my goals; i couldn't care less about it)

Comment: Could you show a piece of source code and screenshots with differences in rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the content didn't match my "pixel-perfect" grid.

If you're working with a pixel-perfect grid, use pixel values. `em` is a relative value that works well only if the layout is able to adapt to different content sizes.

Comment: @pwseo yeah :) Well, there is some substance to the hype of course if you need to build an accessible site, support mobile devices etc. etc. But if you mainly target desktop devices, and have a layout that relies on pixel-perfectness, then `px` is the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so... There should be something like a calc() function on CSS to make things like calc(2em - 1px) :D

Answer (score 2):

I would use `em` only for elements which size depends on font size.

Elements like borders (and its width) usually does not depend on font size.

Comment: I know they don't depend on font-size, but when you mix borders and line-heights (which do depend on font-size), some rounding must occur in some cases, and that's what makes different browsers render things in different places

Answer (score 0):

When using `em` for margin and padding, I've found that the relative measurement can do some funny things.

The `em` can accumulate in nested elements and you find yourself bumping some values back up to align them with outer elements.

This looks fine until you shrink the browser window in very slowly and find that sometimes the values for the nested elements round to a pixel different to the outer parent.

To combat this, I've used `rem` at the parent level to set the font size and found that this allows parent and descendents to work from the same base relative value.